# Scrapy cannot ge text as a string from nav class

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scape data form a supermarket leaf, and I cannot scrape data from it and it always return [] (len(data) = 0) (my target afterwards it's to get the data from /a arial label)[inspect data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLnYw.png)
I make something very stupid?, because I have scrape data many times from other projects.

thank you in advance
I done with selenium

```
class MyprojectSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = 'myProject'
   allowed_domains = ['https://www.ab.gr']
   start_urls = ['https://www.ab.gr/promotion/leaflet']    
   def parse(self, response):
      sel = Selector(response)
      data = response.xpath('//nav[@class="hotspots layer active"]/text()').extract()#
      print(data)#just to check
```

Comment: What if you do `response.css('nav.hotspots')` instead?

Comment: nothing again empty.

Comment: If you download the webpage content with `curl`, you see that there's no `nav` element in the page.  That element must be added and populated with JavaScript.  Use the browser's developer tools to watch the various requests and responses that are generated by the page load, and find the data you want therein.

Comment: thank you for the tip, just a question because I am newbie and I don't know it, what developer tools you are using for scraping ( I have bought 2 courses on udemy, and they just scraped with the inspect.

Comment: I am far from an expert myself but I learned a lot by reading the scrapy documentation.